# When did Vader fight IG-88?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, darth-vader

In the recent strain of Star Wars Marvel comics, the bounty hunters from ESB are making an appearance.  I've heard there's a part somewhere where Vader fights IG-88 (and destroys him), but I can't tell where that is.  Which comic is this from?

Answer (score 1):

> [Darth Vader #13](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader_(2020)_13) is the thirteenth issue of the canon comic series Star
> Wars: Darth Vader. It was written by Greg Pak, illustrated by Guiu
> Vilanova, and published by Marvel Comics on June 23, 2021.

**synopsis:**

> IG-88 was hired by Sly Moore to kill Vader alongside the Droid Crush
> Pirates of Bestoon. She also informed him of the Sith Lord's damaged
> state and gave him the code needed to slice into his armor. Vader and
> the accompanying Sith assassin Ochi of Bestoon were both lured into an
> ambush by a Hutt named Bokku, who sent them after the pirates in an
> attempt to locate the recently stolen Han Solo. Upon arriving at
> Zee-Nine City Seven, Vader and Ochi's ship was sabotaged, causing them
> to crash. They were then attacked by IG-88 and the pirates. During the
> firefight, IG-88 warned Vader that his mechanics were in worse shape
> than the droid's.
>
> When Vader told IG-88 that he had information he required, the droid
> responded that Vader would have to download it from his severed head.
> Vader went to destroy the droid, but IG-88 then used a remote to
> breach Vader's armor, gaining control over the Sith Lord. As he forced
> Vader to hold his lightsaber to his head, the Sith ordered IG-88 to
> tell him who had given him the code. The droid replied that the terms
> of his employment prevented him from sharing the information. While
> IG-88 was distracted, Vader used the Force to take the remote from
> him, allowing him to use it against the droid and force him to blast
> himself in the head. Once IG-88 was subdued, Vader and Ochi forced the
> pirates to retreat and used one of the droid's hands to access a
> terminal he had been using, allowing them to discover various dead
> ends the droid had been chasing, as well as the symbol of crime
> syndicate Crimson Dawn.